# how run two servlets in the same local host?

Tags: java

I was implemented two different servlets in two different web projects in netbeans using tomcat server. When try to run html file for one servlet in one project it running, but when trying to run another servlet in second project the following message appear in browser. This site cannot be reashed in localhost 8080 and localhost refused to connect.
I try to solve it by following steps in cmd:
1-ipconfig /release
2-ipconfig /all
3-ipconfig /flushdns
4-ipconfig /renew
5-netsh int ip set dns
6-netsh winsock reset
and try close proxy and windows firwall but the problem is still.

Comment: You can't run 2 instances of web server on the same port.
You need to configure your web server(Tomcat, Jetty ... whatever) in second project to run on different port - i.e. 8081. Or move both servlets into one project.

Comment: Running two different applications in one web server, means having urls like `http://localhost:8080/app1/servlet1.html` and `http://localhost:8080/app2/servlet2.html`, with an `app1.war` and an `app2.war`.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to serve requests with 2 programs in the same port, which can't be done. What would you expect it would happen if you went to localhost:8080? Both of them would be serving requests in that port, so the OS doesn't allow it.

You can go to `tomcat>conf` folder in one of the projects, and edit the `server.xml` file.

There should be a line saying `Connector port`. Replace `"8080"` for other port, for example `"8081"` and start tomcat.

Comment: And modify the service ports, ssl, etc also.

Comment: @rockfarkas What do you mean by service port? Also I don't think that with the level of this question he is using ssl.

Comment: @ sergpank i try to add two servlets in the same project and calling each servlet from different html client but one servlet is run and the other servlet isnot and appear in browser localhost refused to connect.

Comment: @SergioB, iam deleted one web application from netbeans and remain one application when try running it , the browser still appear the same message that the site can not be reached and localhost refused to connect although the deleted application was run correctly.

Comment: @Shereensaleh It seems like now you have a different problem. If now not even one servlet is working alone and you can't find a solution then post a different question giving all the details.